# fail build if test coverage less than master in team city

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to fail feature branch builds if they have less test coverage than the last successful build of master

I tried adding a extra failure condition by following the steps here

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-failure-conditions.html#BuildFailureConditions-AdditionalFailureConditions

But I can't find a way of referencing the last successful build of master

Is there a special tag automatically set to the "default" branch or do we need to add some code to the build step to auto pin / auto tag it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a [custom build metric](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-failure-conditions.html#BuildFailureConditions-Addingcustombuildmetric) and use a build step to only set the metric when the master branch is being run? You could check the branch name in the TeamCity parameter and only set the value for master? Hopefully this will be easier in the future with [conditional build steps](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2020/03/teamcity-2020-roadmap-part-1-of-2/) (unfortunately not available at the time of answer).